# error: no firebase app '[default]' has been created - call firebase.initializeapp() - React native Android

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, react-native

I can't pass this error when i run it only in android.

Already tested it in iOS and works fine, expect running it on android emulator i get this error
I'm stuck with this, Any help please?

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { AuthProvider } from './AuthProvider';
import Routes from './Routes';

const Providers = () => {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <Routes />
    </AuthProvider>
  );
}

export default Providers;
```

Routes.js

```
import React, {useContext, useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
import {AuthContext} from './AuthProvider';

import AuthStack from './AuthStack';
import AppStack from './AppStack';

const Routes = () => {
  const {user, setUser} = useContext(AuthContext);
  const [initializing, setInitializing] = useState(true);

  const onAuthStateChanged = (user) => {
    setUser(user);
    if (initializing) setInitializing(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscriber = auth().onAuthStateChanged(onAuthStateChanged);
    return subscriber; // unsubscribe on unmount
  }, []);

  if (initializing) return null;

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {user ? <AppStack /> : <AuthStack />}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default Routes;
```